# Check if dates land on specific dates and sort

Tags: php, string

I have a list of dates in a PHP array list. All the dates land either on a Tuesday or Thursday  and are in this format: March 8, 2012. I'm trying to take a list of dates and check a maximum of the next 8 (all of which have to be in the future, none passed) and verify what day of the week each date lands on. Once discovered, I want to put them in 2 separate lists, one for those 4 that land on Tuesday, the other 4 for Thursday (later to be put in separate DIVs). Anyone have an idea on how to get this done?

For sake of separating 200+ lines of code, here's my example:

Today is Monday, November 26, 2012.

Here's my array of dates:

November 27, 2012
November 29, 2012
December 4, 2012
December 6, 2012
December 11, 2012
December 13, 2012
December 18, 2012
December 20, 2012
December 25, 2012
December 27, 2012
January 1, 2013
January 3, 2013
January 8, 2013
January 10, 2013

I want to turn this into 2 lists:

**Tuesday List**
November 27, 2012
December 4, 2012
December 11, 2012
December 18, 2012

**Thursday List**
November 29, 2012
December 6, 2012
December 13, 2012
December 20, 2012

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yes, I've tried hours of research and have the just of the structure already complete.

Comment: By "to see if which date they land on" do you mean "to verify which day of the week the date is?" Also explain what your criteria is in multiple places. For example, what is your criteria for checking future dates? You mention it is a maximum of 8 but could be less. What does "discovered" mean? And what is the criteria for putting dates into two lists? Tuesdays in one, Thursdays in another? Also, post some code please.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your date array (how it is formatted/coded), and then a sample of your desired output (either by image, or code)?

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated my question with more detail and an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
date('w', strtotime($my_date));
```

That should give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple step process (create function, get key, loop through data sorting the dates using key position)

The array (using your posted sample array)-

```
$date_array = array('November 27, 2012','November 29, 2012','December 4, 2012','December 6, 2012','December 11, 2012','December 13, 2012','December 18, 2012','December 20, 2012','December 25, 2012','December 27, 2012','January 1, 2013','January 3, 2013','January 8, 2013','January 10, 2013');
```

Start by creating a function to find the closest `$array` value

```
function closest($array, $number) {

  ksort($array);
  foreach ($array as $a) {
    if (strtotime($a) >= strtotime($number)) return $a;
  }
  return end($array);
  };
```

Find today's date,or then next closest date, using our new function, and then get that `value`'s key-

```
$today = date("F j, Y");
$value = closest($date_array, $today);
$key = array_search($value, $date_array);
```

Create `Tuesday` & `Thursday` arrays to hold the data-

```
$tues_array = array();
$thurs_array = array();
```

Loop through each `date`, starting with the current (or closest to) date 8 times `$key+8` and add them to either the `Tuesday`(2) & `Thursday`(4)

```
for($i=$key;$i<($key+8);$i++){
  $dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($date_array[$i]));
    if ($dayofweek == 2){
        $tues_array[] = $date_array[$i];}
    if ($dayofweek == 4){
        $thurs_array[] = $date_array[$i];}
}
```